# /usr/include/machine/types.h:37:10: fatal error: 'arm/types.h' file not found

Tags: android, iphone, macos, arm

I have spent half a day killing the error. I'm really bored and teared.

The project is converting iPhone App to Android apk by Stella SDK.
The IDE is xCode 4.6.

```
CompileC build-arm-google-android/GLSprite-android.build/Debug/GLSprite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.yeecco.compilers.android.clang.1.0
    cd /Users/anna/samples/GLSprite
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /opt/StellaSDK/bin/android-clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/Debug/include -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/usr/include -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/cocos2d.framework/Headers -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaMedia.framework/Headers -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaStore.framework/Headers -I/Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/GLSprite-android.build/Debug/GLSprite.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/GLSprite-android.build/Debug/GLSprite.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/Debug -F/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks -stella_target arm-google-android -D__STELLA_NANDROID -D__STELLA_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/GLSprite-android.build/Debug/GLSprite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d -c /Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/main.m -o /Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/build-arm-google-android/GLSprite-android.build/Debug/GLSprite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

warning: unknown warning option '-Wreceiver-is-weak' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wint-conversion' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wenum-conversion' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
In file included from /Users/anna/samples/GLSprite/main.m:49:
In file included from /opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:17:
In file included from /opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaKit.framework/Headers/StellaKit.h:7:
In file included from /opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaKit.framework/Headers/SVAcceleration.h:5:
In file included from /opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:11:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:78:
/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:10: fatal error: 'arm/types.h' file not found
#include "arm/types.h"
         ^
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
Command /opt/StellaSDK/bin/android-clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you look at this - https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

The error message is shown because the compiler is looking for types.h in arm folder. If you could provide the file, the compiler will not show this error and continue. Check the documentation of StellaSDK, they should have a "guide" on how to cross compile

Comment: Apparently not.  See [0x8badf00d](http://stackoverflow.com/users/542425/0x8badf00d)'s link to [github](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/72).  It appears an ARM architecture has been dropped.  It is interesting to see how some questions seem obvious at first glance and then they aren't.  Of course, some are [almost funny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733993/makefile-error-127-g-not-found).